# Clear a session when clicking the Back button

Tags: php

Hello guys how can I reset a session when I click

```
input type='button' value='Back' onclick='window.history.back(-1);'
```

It keeps the past stored values in it. The case is a shopping cart. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it about this special button or about the go back functionality of the browser in general?

Comment: about the go back functionality in general. It keeps the shopping xart with products that they have been selected with a particular currency but if i click back and then choose a currency from the beginning it stores the previous amount and does not change it as it should. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems not very well designed.
But if you really want this, you could just call session_destroy on the page your button leads to.

Answer (score 0):

I think what happens is that when you press back on the browser (or execute the JS code in the onclick here, effect is the same), the browser will not hit your server (and thus not destroy the session) but pulls the page out of it's cache... I see it happen on even the most professional web shops.

The fix is to not use the JS code '`window.history.back(-1);`', but onstead make it a link with the href to your cart. (or `onclick="window.location.href = 'shoppingcart.php'"`).That fixes this button.

You can also guard against use of the browser-backbutton by destroying the server-session at the page after the shoppingcart. If the user presses back on the browser (loading the page from cache with old shopping-cart data) and submits again, the server can see that the previous session was destroyed and redirect back to an empty shopping-cart with a message "Your session has been reset"...

Something like that seems to be the norm

Answer (score 0):

At the top of every page you can check if session data already exists and destroy the session with session_destroy()

```
if (isset($_SESSION)) {
 session_destroy();
 }
```